# How to connect to hidden wifi network using nmcli

Tags: linux, networking, wifi

I have to write a linux desktop software which connects to a hidden wifi network. 
If the network is not hidden, my code can connect by calling nmcli, but if it is hidden, it can not add the connection. However, I can create a new network using the GUI of the Network Manager, so I think it is not impossible. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Okay, I have the solution. We know the ssid and the password.

```
nmcli c add type wifi con-name <connect name> ifname wlan0 ssid <ssid>
nmcli con modify <connect name> wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk
nmcli con modify <connect name> wifi-sec.psk <password>
nmcli con up <connect name>
```

If we dont need the connection anymore:

```
nmcli c delete <connect name>
```

Comment: Just to be clear.  When doing delete, <connect name> is either `id NAME` or `uuid UUID` where NAME and UUID can be obtained via **`nmcli -p c`**.  E.g. **`nmcli c delete id esp8266_ap`**. This is referring to nmcli tool, version 0.9.8.8.

Comment: best thing of doing this is that once added, it is persistent. Reboot/shutdown, it shall keep your connection up once linux is initiated!

Answer (score 16):

This works fine for me:

```
nmcli dev wifi connect "abc" password 123 hidden yes
```

Comment: This didn't work for me™
 I received an error: "network manager failed to scan hidden SSID: Scanning not allowed while already scanning." The selected answer worked for me however.

Comment: You just need to wait a few seconds for the scan to finish.

Answer (score 1):

While doing some experimenting, I found that you can use both echnotux's and Pocokman's answers to get it to connect. i.e

```
nmcli c add type wifi con-name <connect name> ifname wlan0 ssid <ssid>
nmcli dev wifi connect <ssid> password <password> hidden yes
nmcli c delete <connect name>
```

This simplifies it quite a bit.

Answer (score -1):

As of 2023, it is much easier to setup a connection with a hidden SSID using nmcli:

```
nmcli dev wifi connect --ask <ssid> name <ssid> hidden yes
```

You can also use `password <password>` if you don't want to use `--ask`.